# Read messages on a subscription added on a specific date

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I have the code below which works fine to read messages from a servicebus topic but I have 300000 messages in the subscription

The message I need was sent on a specific date

Is there a way to change the processor to only return messages for a specific date?

```
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        await AdditionAsync();

        return 0;
    }



    // the client that owns the connection and can be used to create senders and receivers
    ServiceBusClient client;

    // the processor that reads and processes messages from the subscription
    ServiceBusProcessor processor;

    // handle received messages
    static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        // TODO: Replace the <TOPIC-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME> placeholder
        var body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(body);


        if (body.Contains("My Label")) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {body} from subscription: <TOPIC-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME>");
        }
        
    }

    // handle any errors when receiving messages
    static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task AdditionAsync()
    {

        // Set the transport type to AmqpWebSockets so that the ServiceBusClient uses the port 443. 
        // If you use the default AmqpTcp, ensure that ports 5671 and 5672 are open.
        var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        };

        var client = new ServiceBusClient(
            "Connection string",
             clientOptions);

        // The Service Bus client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
        // of the application, which is best practice when messages are being published or read
        // regularly.
        //
        // Create the clients that we'll use for sending and processing messages.
        // TODO: Replace the <NAMESPACE-CONNECTION-STRING> placeholder
        
        var test = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions()
        {

        }
        // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
        // TODO: Replace the <TOPIC-NAME> and <SUBSCRIPTION-NAME> placeholders
        var processor = client.CreateProcessor("TOpic", "subscription", new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
  
        try
        {
            // add handler to process messages
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

            // add handler to process any errors
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

            // start processing 
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Wait for a minute and then press any key to end the processing");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // stop processing 
            Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the receiver...");
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
        }
        finally
        {
            // Calling DisposeAsync on client types is required to ensure that network
            // resources and other unmanaged objects are properly cleaned up.
            await processor.DisposeAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Paul

Answer (score 0):

> I followed on read message from Azure Service Bus on specific date.

- Create a Service Bus, [topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.primitives.partitionreceiver?view=azure-dotnet) and [Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=passwordless)

[image]

- In Visual Studio enter this code

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

class Program
{
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a date to filter messages (YYYY-MM-DD):");
        string dateInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateInput, out DateTime filterDate))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid date format. Exiting program.");
            return -1;
        }

        await ReceiveMessagesAsync(filterDate);

        return 0;
    }

    
    static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        var body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(body);

        // TODO: Replace the <TOPIC-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME> placeholder
        if (body.Contains("My Label"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {body} from subscription: <TOPIC-SUBSCRIPTION-NAME>");
        }
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }

    // handle any errors when receiving messages
    static Task ErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(DateTime filterDate)
    {
        // TODO: Replace the <NAMESPACE-CONNECTION-STRING>, <TOPIC-NAME>, and <SUBSCRIPTION-NAME> placeholders
        string connectionString = "<NAMESPACE-CONNECTION-STRING> ";
        string topicName = "<TOPIC-NAME>";
        string subscriptionName = "<SUBSCRIPTION-NAME>";

        
        var clientOptions = new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        };

        var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString, clientOptions);

        
        var processor = client.CreateProcessor(topicName, subscriptionName, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

        try
        {
            
            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;

           
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

         
            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

            Console.WriteLine($" Getting  messages from Service Bus on {subscriptionName} topic {topicName} filtered by date {filterDate:yyyy-MM-dd}. Press any key to stop receiving messages.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            
            Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the receiver...");
            await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped receiving messages");
        }
        finally
        {
            
            await processor.DisposeAsync();
            await client.DisposeAsync();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

-In .exe enter the required details.

[image]